# Is there a way I can access multiple JSON objects in array(struct) one by one in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a bit new to pyspark and json parsing and I am stuck in some certain scenario . Let me explain first What I am trying to do , I have a json file in which there is data element , that data element is an array  which contains two other json objects . The given json file is below

```
 {
    "id": "da20d14c.92ba6",
    "type": "Data Transformation Node",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "x": 380,
    "y": 240,
    "typeofoperation":"join",
    "wires": [
        ["da20d14c.92ba6","da20d14c.93ba6"]
    ],
 "output":true, 
 "data":[
      {
         "metadata_id":"3434",
         "id":"1",
         "first_name":"Brose",
         "last_name":"Eayres",
         "email":"beayres0@archive.org",
         "gender":"Male",
         "postal_code":null
      },
      {
         "metadata_id":"3434",
         "id":"2",
         "first_name":"Brose",
         "last_name":"Eayres",
         "email":"beayres0@archive.org",
         "gender":"Male",
         "postal_code":null
      }
   ]

 }
```

Now What I want to do is to iterate over that data array one by one: meaning iterate to first object of json store it into a dataframe and than iterate to the second object and store it into another dataframe and than do a full join or any type of join on them.(is it possible)

If yes , how to do this in pyspark. So far what I have done is
tried to explode it but data is exploded at once rather than on by one

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

dataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("nodeWithTwoRddJoin.json")

dataNode = dataFrame.select(explode("data").alias("Data_of_node"))

dataNode.show()
```

But the above code gives me a collective dataset. Than I used

```
firstDataSet = dataNode.collect()[0]
secondDataSet =  dataNode.collect()[1]
```

These lines give me a row which I cannot concert back to dataframe. Any suggestions and solutions

Comment: Let me first ask - it is just essentially a row of data, why do you need a whole dataframe for it?  Do you anticipate another collection inside of the row? Or do you just want to join the two rows

Comment: well , if it possible that I can apply a join on these two Rows than It would be fine as well because I did not know whether we can apply a join on a two different rows or can we ? The reason I am converting those rows into dataframes is because my application takes a data frame as input and outputs a datafarme as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a map on each row of your dataframe which splits the contents of one of its columns into two new columns. Separating the results of this into two dataframes is trivial afterwards. To achieve this, I used a simple function which returns the desired index from an array:

```
def splitArray(array, pos):
    return array[pos]
```

You can apply this function like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

mapped = dataFrame.select(
    splitArray(f.col('data'), 0).alias('first'),
    splitArray(f.col('data'), 1).alias('second'))
```

(I used the build in ´col´ function to select the data column. Not sure if there is a more elegant way to achieve this.)

The result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|first                                                |second                                               
|
+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|[beayres0@archive.org, Brose, Male, 1, Eayres, 3434,]|[beayres0@archive.org, Brose, Male, 2, Eayres, 3434,]|
+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

To but the columns in different dfs, just select them:

```
firstDataSet = mapped.select('first')
secondDataSet =  mapped.select('second)
```

Comment: yeah , that will do, and further querying will be done like that email = firstDataSet.select(col("first.email")). Thank you ! you  are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

This puts them in two dataframes at least

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df_with_id = dataNode.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id())

max_id = df_with_id.agg({"id": "max"}).collect()[0]["max(id)"]


first_df = df_with_id.where("id = {maxid}".format(maxid=max_id))
second_df = df_with_id.where("id != {maxid}".format(maxid=max_id))
```

Comment: actually it does not  work , it gives an exception at   max_id = df_with_id.agg({"id": "max"}).collect()[0]["max(id)"] line , the error is  AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'